# Converting from boost unordered to tbb concurrent hash map

Tags: c++, hashmap, tbb

I am very new to C++ and I have been searching, in vain, for a beginner's tutorial on tbb concurrent hash map. I have been using boost unordered hash map in my C++ program, and now I would like to use tbb's concurrent hash map since multiple threads will be writing to the hash map at once.

I am doing the following four operations on boost's hash map:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<string, std::vector<int> > MAP;
MAP myMap;
```

1. Inserting into myMap:

   ```
   string key = "somestring"
   int somevalue = 1 
   myMap[key].push_back(somevalue);
   ```
2. Iterating through all the keys in myMap:

   ```
   BOOST_FOREACH(MAP::value_type pair, myMap)
   {
           string key  = pair.first;
   }
   ```
3. Returning the value associated with a key:

   ```
   MAP::const_iterator iter = myMap.find("somekey");
   ```

How can I achieve 1, 2, and 3, using tbb concurrent hash map? Note that I perform 2 and 3 only **after** all threads are done with their inserts

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply change your typedef to `typedef tbb::concurrent_unordered_map<string, std::vector<int> > MAP;` and use the container with multiple threads safely.

The insert, iterators (begin .. end) and find methods all work in the same way, but unlike unordered_map they are thread safe.

Comment: ..unless concurrent erase() is needed since it is not thread-safe in tbb::concurrent_unordered_map

Comment: If that's the case, then why does tbb have acessor and const accessor for inserts and finds respectively??

Comment: @NewToAndroid, don't mix concurrent_hash_map (with `erase()` and accessors) with concurrent_unordered_map (with `unsafe_erase()` and iterators instead of accessors)